# Read from source file and split the contents into two other separate files

Tags: java, file-io, java-io

My goal is that I wish to read from a file with the name "input.txt", which has  10 lines of text, and then write 5 lines from the original into two other files with the names "test1.txt" and "test2.txt".  I'm using the following code, but it is not working - please help me.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;


public class main {

public static void main (String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{


BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (new FileReader("bin/input.txt"));
File file = new File("bin/test2.txt");
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("bin/test.txt"));


Scanner sc = new Scanner (br);

int i = 0;

while (sc.hasNextLine()){

    sc.nextLine();
    i++;
    System.out.print(i);
    int n = (i+1)/2;
    System.out.print("\n"+n);

    writer.write(sc.nextLine().toString());
    writer.newLine();
    if (n==5){
        writer.close();
    }
}


if (sc != null){
    sc.close();
}



}
}
```

Comment: When you use `java.io`, you should create separate input/output streams for any file which you use.

Answer (score 1):

this will read from single file and splitting content into two file.

```
        int count = 0;
        BufferedReader br = null;
        FileWriter fileWriter1 = new FileWriter("G:\\test1.txt");
        FileWriter fileWriter2 = new FileWriter("G:\\test2.txt");

        try {
            String currentLine;
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("G:\\input.txt"));
            while ((currentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                count++;
                if (count <= 5) {
                    fileWriter1.write(currentLine + "\n");
                } else {
                    fileWriter2.write(currentLine + "\n");
                }
            }
        } finally {
            if (br != null) {
                br.close();
            }
            fileWriter1.close();
            fileWriter2.close();
        }
```

Comment: but in output txt file , when arrived to end line, don't jump to next line.in this code line: 'code' fileWriter1.write(currentLine + "\n"); 'code'

Comment: second txt output file is Cluttered. my input text is Persian. how can i fixed it?

Answer (score 0):

Create two BufferedWriter instead of one with two files and then follow the below procedure:

```
 count <- 0
 while scanner hasNextLine
 do
     string line <- scanner's next Line
     if (count > 4) {
         writer2.write line
     } else {
         writer1.write line
     }
     count <- count + 1
 done
 finally close all three resources.
```